# Transferring data from Azure Blob to Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: cloud, azure-data-factory, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) for this task but not able to find sink for "Salesforce Marketing Cloud". Although there is sink for "Salesforce" and "Salesforce Service Cloud" . What other option are there to achieve this task apart/within Azure Data Factory  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy active doesn't support Salesforce Marketing Cloud as sink for now:

[image]

You may achieve that in code level, such as Azure Function and Databricks. Then run the scripts in Data Factory.